# How to get an array as output using rexx

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, zos, rexx, db2-zos

I'm testing some functions of Db2 for z/OS, and right now I'm having troubles when I try to call a Stored Procedure through REXX.

Below is the code to create the Data Type that I need to return in my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE TYPE *******.ARRAY_TESTE AS VARCHAR(186) ARRAY[200];
```

This is the DDL that I used to create the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE *******.TESTE_EMP2           
  (OUT EDLEVELARR MYVARRTYPE,                 
   OUT LASTNAMEARR MYVARRTYPE)                
  VERSION MEDIAN_V1                           
  LANGUAGE SQL                                
  NOT DETERMINISTIC                           
  READS SQL DATA                              
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT                        
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1                       
  DISABLE DEBUG MODE                          
  PARAMETER CCSID EBCDIC                      
  QUALIFIER *******                           
  PACKAGE OWNER ******                       
  ASUTIME NO LIMIT                            
  COMMIT ON RETURN NO                         
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS                   
  NODEFER PREPARE                             
  CURRENT DATA NO                             
  DEGREE 1                                    
  DYNAMICRULES RUN                            
  WITHOUT EXPLAIN                             
  WITHOUT IMMEDIATE WRITE                     
  ISOLATION LEVEL CS                          
  WITHOUT KEEP DYNAMIC                        
  OPTHINT ''                                  
  RELEASE AT COMMIT                           
  REOPT NONE                                                    
  VALIDATE RUN                                                  
  ROUNDING DEC_ROUND_HALF_EVEN                                  
  DECIMAL(31)                                                   
  BUSINESS_TIME SENSITIVE NO                                    
  SYSTEM_TIME SENSITIVE NO                                      
  ARCHIVE SENSITIVE NO                                          
  BEGIN                                                         
    SELECT  ARRAY_AGG(VARCHAR(EDLEVEL)), ARRAY_AGG(LASTNAME)    
    INTO EDLEVELARR, LASTNAMEARR                                
    FROM DSN81110.EMP ;                                         
  END `
```

And this is the REXX that I used to call the stored Procedure

```
LOCAL_DB2 = ****                                                  
ADDRESS DSNREXX                                                   
RC = 'SUBCOM DSNREXX'                                             
OUTTRAP TESTE_DATA.                                               
TESTE_DATA2.                                                      
IF RC <> 0 THEN DO                                                
   S_RC = RXSUBCOM('ADD','DSNREXX','DSNREXX')                     
END                                                               
                                                                  
"CONNECT " LOCAL_DB2                                              
IF SQLCODE <> +0 THEN DO                                          
   MY_ERROR = 'ERROR CONNECTING TO DB2 ' LOCAL_DB2                
END                                                               
EXECSQL "CALL *******.TESTE_EMP2(:TESTE_DATA.,:TESTE_DATA2.)"     
IF (SQLCODE<>0) THEN                                              
CALL SQL_ERROR                                                    
                                                                  
       ADDRESS DSNREXX                                            
          "DISCONNECT"                                            
           S_RC = RXSUBCOM('DELETE','DSNREXX','DSNREXX')          
 EXIT
```

Right now I'm having the SQLCODE

```
-301 THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR ARGUMENT NUMBER position-number CANNOT BE USED AS SPECIFIED BECAUSE OF ITS DATA TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is self explanatory. The user-defined-array-datatype is not one of the supported data-types for REXX calling Db2 stored procedures, at current versions .

Refer to this [documentation page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_callspfromrexxprocedure.html) to see the types that REXX supports and the corresponding SQL data type,